# MVC5 Fail to GET php api using ajax after submit a form and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC5. Want to submit a form and then pass all input value to a php api.

If I submit my input using form,passing value to php api and do not redirect to other action , it will work.

But if I redirect to index after submit form , it will fail.

I have to REDIRECT to index after submit , but don't know how to fix.

I've tested my api and it works.

This is html View:

```
<form  id="registerForm" method="post" action="~/OverTime/Add">                                   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="OverTime_Description" name="OverTime_Description" />
    <input class="form-control" id="DateStart" name="DateStart" type="text"/> 
    <button onclick="log()" id="submit" type="submit">add</button>
</form>
```

This is ajax php api:

```
function log() {
    var OverTime_Description = $('#OverTime_Description').val();
    var DateStart = $('#DateStart').val();

        if (OverTime_Description != "" && DateStart != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://severip/lineMsg.php?Group=101&Message=' + OverTime_Description + ":" + DateStart,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function () {

                }

            });
        }
}
```

Passing two input text value which ID are OverTime_Description and DateStart.

My redirection in my OverTime crontroller:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.Overtimess = OverTimeRepository.GetCollections().ToList();
        ViewBag.Members = MemberRepository.GetCollections().ToList();
        if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
        {
            OverTime _overTime = new OverTime();
            _overTime.OverTime_Description = Request.Form["OverTime_Description"];
            _overTime.OverTime_StartDate = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form["DateStart"]);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(OverTimeRepository.GetCollections());
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it will fail? Where in the code the `Add` controller action is being called?

Comment: add crontroller is in my VIEW <form  id="registerForm" method="post" action="~/OverTime/Add">

Comment: fail means my ajax GET url fail if I redirect to Index after submit the form. But, if I don't redirect to other page , ajax url works.

Comment: What error do you get when Ajax url fails?

Comment: no error , maybe my input text is cleared when submit , so that OverTime_Description and DateStart is null , is there any possible

Comment: Wait a moment, you're calling `RedirectToAction` method and then passing it your controller name?

Comment: it is strange that it only happens when i redirect to other page. if i submit the form and stay in the same page, passing value success.

Comment: is it wrong ? how should I fix it?

Comment: First parameter of `RedirectToAction` method should be **action name**. If you want to redirect to another page you should call `RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");` or `RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName", routeValues);`. Otherwise, if it's a redirection to the same page another action you should do `RedirectToAction("actionName");`

Comment: my RedirectToAction works , it will redirect to controller Overtime action Index

Comment: Is CORS enabled on the Api? Better to try a simple Get Url, returning a list, to make sure truly connected to Api and getting data.